# AES decryption not working properly in Marshmallow and Lollipop but it work fine in JellyBean in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am new in android development.I just try to Encryption and Decryption string in Android. Encryption of String is work fine in all version of android till now. but when i try to do decryption of string it throw error **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted** in Lollipop and Marshmallow.
I use Below class for Encryption and Decryption.

**public class AESencryptPassword** 
{

```
static String encryptedString;

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);

}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    Log.d("EncrypteedCode=", encrypted);

    encryptedString = encrypted;

    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

public static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    Log.d("EnterInHouse", "EnterInHouse");

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    Log.d("EnterInHouse", cipher.toString());
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
   byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);


    Log.d("Exit", "Exit");
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}

public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
}
```

}

I just try to call these method encryption and decryption code in Log of android.
 String text="amit";
 String newEncryptedPassWord=AESencryptPassword.encrypt(seedValue,text);
 Log.d("newEncryptedPassWord",newEncryptedPassWord);`enter code here`

String newPassDecrypt=AESencryptPassword.decrypt(seedValue,newEncyptedPassWord);
 Log.d("newPassDecrypt",newPassDecrypt);

Comment: Hi Amit and a belated welcome to SO. This is a dupe, but if you have any followup questions, please don't forget to put your runtime environment (Java / Android) in the tags.

Comment: thanks for suggestion Maarten Bodewes